# User input only occurs once or never stops during loop

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am attempting a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, find sum, positive, negative and average. My issue is that either it will only run and allow one integer to be typed and then do nothing, or with the following code, it never stops letting you enter numbers therefore I can't get past.  I have the number = 0 output correct.

```
public class Compute {

// Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sum = 0;
        positive = 0;
        negative = 0;
        total = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
        int numbers = input.nextInt();

        do {
            if (numbers > 0) {
                positive++;//add 1 to positive count
            } else if (numbers < 0) {
                negative++;//add 1 to negative count
            }//end else if

            sum += numbers; //add integer input to sum

            numbers = input.nextInt();
            total++;
        } while (numbers != 0);

        if (numbers == 0) {
            System.out.println("No numbers are entered except " + numbers);
        }//end if
    }
}
```

Comment: Please work on formatting your code better. You'll get better answers if folks can easily read your code.

Comment: Also, consider outputting a prompt to the user input before every call to input.nextInt(). Else, how will you know it's time to enter new input? Something like: `System.out.print("Please enter the next number: ");` followed by `numbers = input.nextIne();`

Comment: You need to consume the line terminator before calling `nextInt` again.

Comment: @Perception: Usually this is so, especially when mixing Scanner calls to `nextInt()` and similar methods with a `nextLine()` call, but if the Scanner only gets simple tokens such as int, then I don't think that this is necessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - tested and confirmed. This is mainly an issue of display.

Comment: His code also doesn't compile. @Lish -- please only post real code, not sort-of code.

Comment: Yep, logic error is here: `if (numbers == 0) {...` That's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. to terminate the loop and see output type 0 as input at any time of execution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compute {

    // Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sum = 0;
        int positive = 0;
        int negative = 0;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
        int numbers = input.nextInt();

        do {

            if (numbers > 0) {
                positive++;// add 1 to positive count
                sum += numbers; // add integer input to sum
            }

            else if (numbers < 0) {
                negative++;// add 1 to negative count
                sum -= numbers; // add integer input to sum
            }

            numbers = input.nextInt();
            total++;

        } while (numbers != 0);

        System.out.println("The number of positives is \t " + positive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is \t " + negative);
        System.out.println("The total count of number is \t " + total);
        System.out.println("The sum of all number is    \t" + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is           \t"
                + ((double) sum / (positive + negative)));

    }// end main
}// end Compute
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet should give you a good example on how to read integers from console:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
  int i = scanner.nextInt();
  // ...
} while (scanner.hasNext());
```

The `scanner.hasNext()` method call will block until user enter the next number on console